# How to store multiple integers in an array from one prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I cannot figure out how to store multiple integers in an array from one prompt
like

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
num_array = []
num_array.push(prompt("Enter x amount of integers: "));
console.log(num_array)
```

in the console, it asks:
Enter x amount of integers:
so i enter: 7 6 5 9 21 4 6 99 820
when the console logs the array, instead of it showing: '7 6 5 9 21 4 6 99 820'
I wanna know if it's possible for it to show: '7', '6', '5', '9', '21', '4', '6', '99', '820'

Comment: `prompt().split(" ")`?

Comment: @HenryWoody it works

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `split()` function to split the input string based on a space, or comma, your choice. And then you could use `parseInt()` to convert the substrings into integers.

Try this:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
let input = prompt("Enter x amount of integers: ");
let num_array = input.split(' ').map(num => parseInt(num));
console.log(num_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt-sync` does not automatically split the input string into an array of numbers. We have to do it manually. Something like:

```js
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
let num_array = [];

let input = prompt("Enter x amount of integers: ");
let input_array = input.split(' ');

input_array.forEach(item => {
  num_array.push(Number(item));
});

console.log(num_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the input into individual integers:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const num_array_input = prompt("Enter x amount of integers: ");
const num_array_output = num_array_input.split(' ').map(Number);
console.log(num_array_output);
```

```js
const num_array_input = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
const num_array_output = num_array_input.split(' ').map(Number);
console.log(num_array_output);
```